# Python3.9 Module not found import error for local package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

```
├── README.md
├── src/
│   └── ptmodeling
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── driver.py
│       ├── features.py
│       └── modeling.py
└── tests/
```

When I run `python3 driver.py` from within the ptmodeling directory I get
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ptmodeling'` . I tried running from project root, adding everything to PYTHONPATH and nothing works with the driver.py below

**driver.py**

```
import logging
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
print(sys.path)

from ptmodeling.modeling import ModelEngine
from ptmodeling.features import FeatureExtractor
```

But this works

**driver.py**

```
import logging
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
print(sys.path)

from modeling import Model
from features import Feature
```

Comment: You could try running it as a module `python -m src.ptmodeling`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem here? Your question itself has the answer. And to your doubt, your code where you get an error won't work because python is looking into the `ptmodeling` folder inside the current directory. This means you're surfing through `src/ptmodeling/ptmodeling` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Shouldn't it work from any of the upper level directories then with the full import defined? I get the module import error at any level.

Comment: That's now how it works. Imports are defined from two ways: 
1. `The PATH`
2. `The Relative Directory`